# The Webpack project is not loading scss

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, sass

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-threejs",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Keivan Sina personal website.",
  "keywords": [
    "three.js",
    "webpack",
    "glsl",
    "glslify"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "Keivan Sina",
    "url": "http://k1sina.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production --config config/prod.js",
    "start": "webpack serve --config config/dev.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@brunoimbrizi/controlkit": "^0.1.93",
    "@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.5.7",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
    "browser-detect": "^0.2.28",
    "domready": "^1.0.8",
    "glsl-noise": "0.0.0",
    "gsap": "^2.1.3",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "isotope-layout": "^3.0.6",
    "jquery-bridget": "^2.0.1",
    "odometer": "^0.4.8",
    "stats.js": "^0.17.0",
    "swiper": "^6.1.1",
    "three": "^0.98.0",
    "wow.js": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "glslify": "^6.2.1",
    "glslify-import-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "glslify-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

Here is the common webpack rules:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const variables = require('./variables.js');

const __root = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/scripts/index.js'],
    // index: '/src/scripts/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__root, 'dist'),
    filename: 'scripts/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'scripts/[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
          },
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
        use: ['glslify-import-loader', 'raw-loader', 'glslify-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /three\/examples\/js/,
        use: 'imports-loader?THREE=three',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            interpolate: true,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|webp)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
            output: 'images',
            esModule: false
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'three-examples': path.join(__root, './node_modules/three/examples/js'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], { root: __root }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__root, 'static'),
      },
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/cases.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'cases.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/iransalary.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'iransalary.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/safarmarket.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'safarmarket.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/rideradar.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'rideradar.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/logodesign.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'logodesign.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/artvan.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'artvan.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/orugso.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'orugso.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/navaaz.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'navaaz.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/iotanalytic.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'iotanalytic.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/smartdent.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'smartdent.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/ledgercover.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['index'],
      filename: 'ledgercover.html',
      templateParameters: variables,
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      THREE: 'three',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contentHash].css',
    }),
  ],
};
```

And here is the index.js

```
import ready from 'domready';
import App from './App';
import './agansy';
import './../sass/style.scss';

ready(() => {
    window.app = new App();
    window.app.init();
});
```

I have a Webpack project and it used to work before. I upgraded my dependencies and now the scss is not being compiled. I checked the compiled files and there is no sign of css code.

I als tried to replace

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
}
```

with

```
{
  test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
},
```

but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          // "style-loader",
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              esModule: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          { loader: "sass-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
        ],
      },
```

then import the main `scss` file in the app.js or bootstrap file of your project.

Comment: I did what you suggested but still no sign of compiled CSS or any error.